# Derivative of a functional involving integral and level set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, integral-operators

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain. For $u\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, define the functional
$$F(u) = \int_{\{u=0\}}g(x) \; \mathrm{d}x$$
where eg. $u \in H^2(\Omega) \cap C^0(\bar\Omega)$ and  $g \in C^\infty(\bar\Omega)$.

I am looking for differentiability results for $F$ as a map from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a function space (which can be chose as convenient), and want to know what the derivative satisfies.

The differentiability could be in a Frechet, Hadamard, directional or  subdifferential sense.

Originally [asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809009/derivative-of-functional-involving-integral-over-level-set)

Comment: Seems to me it could be discontinuous if you don't really have any restrictions on $u$ because the size of the zero set could easily bump up from zero to some $\delta > 0$ suddenly.

Comment: @SBK Yes, I think so and also depending on the direction taken. I just need some vague ideas of how people approach this particular problem

Comment: I suppose this will boil down to having the level sets (intersected with the support of $g$) depend continuously on the respective function w.r.t. the function space $X$ topology; that seems rather unpleasant at first glance. (Take constant functions with value $\varepsilon$ and let $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$, that will converge uniformly or in $H^2(\Omega)$ to the zero function but the zero level sets jump from $\{0\}$ to $\Omega$ in the limit, not nice!)

Comment: Which measure do you use on $\{u = 0\}$? Maybe one can do something, if one assumes $\nabla u \ne 0$ on $\{u = 0\}$ (in a certain sense). If $u$ has some further regularity, this will render $\{u = 0\}$ a submanifold.